# Eclipse RCP long tooltips disappear

Tags: eclipse, long-integer, rcp, tooltip

In my RCP application I have set up tree viewers and tables to have tool tips. Everything goes well, tool tips appear right to the mouse cursor position, as long as they fit the screen. If the don't, they disappear in one tenth of a moment after they appeared.

Comment: Eclipse removes tool tips which intersect the mouse pointer. To avoid this problem I have added for tool tips small vertical and horizontal shifts by implementing the Point getToolTipShift(Object object) method of CellLabelProvider

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse removes tool tips which intersect the mouse pointer. To avoid this problem I have added for tool tips small vertical and horizontal shifts by implementing the Point getToolTipShift(Object object) method of CellLabelProvider